# In a SQL merge, what would be behavior in case `when not matched and <condition>` fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

Consider the following `merge`:

```
merge tgtTable tgt
using ( <record from srcTable> ) src
    on ( tgt.id = src.id )
when matched 
    and ('sha1', isnull(tgt.field, '')) != hash('sha1', isnull(src.field, ''))
then update
    set tgt.otherFields = src.otherFields
when not matched by target
then insert
    (id, field) values (src.id, src.field)
```

This is not a very difficult query, but I need some clarification with `when matched and <condition>` and the `when not matched`.

For example, in my **source table** I have an record like this:

```
------- SRC Table --------
ID | FIELD   | OTHERFIELDS
------------------------
5  | a_value | ...
```

Let's say the **target table** has one very similar record:

```
------- TGT Table --------
ID | FIELD   | OTHERFIELDS
------------------------
5  | value_b | ...
```

When the merge statement runs, they are a match (`tgt.id = src.id`), but they will fail the `and` condition (`('sha1', isnull(tgt.field, '')) != hash('sha1', isnull(src.field, ''))`.

What actually failed in the example was the `and` condition and not the match itself. In this case, will the insert in the `not matched by target` be executed?

Comment: Give sample data please.

Comment: Define "failed". Did you get an error message? Did it update something incorrectly? Or maybe it didn't update something?

Comment: @NEED It's a theoretical question. I made my example a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @Sean Let's define "failure" as just "returns false".

Comment: OK. So for the row in question it matches the merge condition but not the additional predicates right? As coded it would not touch that row. It of course is NOT going to fall into the not matched section. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, correct! I'm having a few problems with our database and I was suspecting that this could be the case. If, even though it fails the `and` condition and it's NOT going to fall into the not matched, I have to investigate a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It's exactly like with CASE clause.
See example B here : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx